# Insert into postgres view using defaults based on view definition

Tags: postgresql, view

Нello! Say that a `vehicle` can be of type "car", "truck", or "motorcycle". Each vehicle has a `top_speed` (in km/h) and a `license_plate` string.

E.g.

```
CREATE TABLE vehicle (
  type VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  top_speed INTEGER NOT NULL,
  license_plate VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO vehicle (type, top_speed, license_plate)
  VALUES
    ('car', 120, 'abc123'),
    ('truck', 110, 'def456'),
    ('motorcycle', 140, 'ghi789');
```

Now add views for each type of vehicle:

```
CREATE VIEW car AS (SELECT * FROM vehicle WHERE type='car');
CREATE VIEW truck AS (SELECT * FROM vehicle WHERE type='truck');
CREATE VIEW motorcycle AS (SELECT * FROM vehicle WHERE type='motorcycle');
```

All this is fine and dandy. But I run into an uncomfortable situation when I try to insert into these views:

```
INSERT INTO car (type, top_speed, license_plate)
  VALUES
    ('car', 160, 'v4n1ty');
```

My issue is that I'm already inserting into a view called "car"... why should I have to bother to specify that `type = 'car'`?

If I omit the `type` column from this insert query I'll get an error that the `type` column isn't allowed to contain `NULL`. It seems like postgres won't default omitted values even when they *could* be gleaned from the view's definition.

**Is there a way I can get postgres to look to the view's definition in order to provide defaults for omitted columns in `INSERT` queries?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is very powerful [rule system](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rules.html) in PostgreSQL.

Additionally to your code:

```
create rule car_insert as on insert to car do instead
  insert into vehicle(type, top_speed, license_plate)
    values('car', new.top_speed, new.license_plate);

insert into car(top_speed, license_plate) values(160,'v4n1ty');

table car;
┌──────┬───────────┬───────────────┐
│ type │ top_speed │ license_plate │
├──────┼───────────┼───────────────┤
│ car  │       120 │ abc123        │
│ car  │       160 │ v4n1ty        │
└──────┴───────────┴───────────────┘
```

Answer (score 12):

Postgres can prevent you from inserting rows into a view that would not be visible in the view.  The syntax is [`WITH CHECK OPTION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createview.html) at the end of `CREATE VIEW`.

Inferring column values from a view's `where` clause is not supported.  You could simulate it with an [`instead of insert` trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/triggers.html):

```
CREATE FUNCTION insertCar() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO vehicle
        (type, top_speed, license_plate)
    VALUES
        ('car', new.top_speed, new.license_plate);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER insertCarTrigger INSTEAD OF INSERT ON car
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insertCar();
```

Comment: Thank you for the CHECK option suggestion. I was almost starting to implement either a trigger or rule, which for my case isn't necessary.